# Linq to SQL Data Concurrency - Is it safe to use only PKs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, concurrency

I am getting an error in my MVC-based website surrounding data concurrency in Linq to SQL:

"Row Not Found Or Changed"

After reading several posts on here it seems as though an accepted solution is to set all non-Primary key fields to UpdateCheck = false in the dbml designer.  Before taking the plunge with this, I wanted to ask, will I be losing anything if I do this?

To be honest, it seems to me like this should always be the case, as using the primary key should be the fastest way to find a record anyway.  This would be assuming that you don't have any composite PKs.  I'm not terribly familiar with data concurrency scenarios, but am I missing something here?

Thanks for your time!

**[EDIT]**

Thanks for the feedback guys!  To give some more detail, the specific scenario I have is this:

I  have an Article table with a number of fields (title, content, author, etc.).  One of the fields that gets updated very frequently (anytime anyone views the article), is a popularity field, which gets incremented with every click.  I saw the original error mentioned above when I updated the article text in the database.  Then navigated to that article on the live site (which attempted to update the popularity field).

For starters it sounds like I need to NOT be using a shared DataContext.  Beyond that, maybe look into setting certain fields to UpdateCheck never.  That being said, **I definitely do not want the Article Popularity to not get update due to some concurrency issue.  So with that being the case, is there a way for me to ensure this with optimistic concurrency?**

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

I do sometimes change `UpdateCheck` to `Never` on all but the primary key(s) on entity classes in the designer myself. What you lose is notification of interim changes to the data since you loaded it; what you end up with is a "last change wins" type of scenario. If that is OK in your situation, then... fine.

There are situations where that is definitely *not* a good thing to do. For instance, checking/adjusting a bank account funds balance... or any situation where an alternation to a field is going to be based on a calculation with the current value as one of the operands.

Comment: I also wanted to add; If you are frequently having concurrency errors, it's possible you may be doing something in a somewhat non-optimal way;

You generally should not be caching the `DataContext` or the entity objects themselves between web page calls. The Action method that does the data changes should be loading the entity object anew from a fresh DataContext, changing the properties as needed, then saving.

If a site has high-usage, you will see some concurrency things happening there, but it might not be all THAT common; so I thought I'd add that, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback!  So it sounds like I'm doing several things wrong here.  For one, I am in fact using a Shared (static in c#) dataContext object, through which all of my queries, inserts, and updates are performed.  From what you're telling me, this is bad practice.  I will look into making some adjustments here.  Aside from that, I could see setting Update Check to false on certain fields as being problematic.  I have added more information to my original post to detail this.

Answer (score 0):

> set all non-Primary key fields to UpdateCheck = false in the dbml designer. Before taking the plunge with this, I wanted to ask, will I be losing anything if I do this?

The job of **concurrency mechanisms** is to prevent multiple users from stomping each others changes.  **Pessimistic concurrency** achieves this by locking out changes to a record when it is read.  Then unlocking the record when changes are complete.  **Optimistic concurrency** achieves this by remembering what the record looked like when it was read, and then not modifying the record if it has changed.

Linq to Sql uses **optimistic concurrency**.  If you set the UpdateCheck property that way, you are disabling **optimistic concurrency** checking.

Consider this record:

- Customer (Name = "Bob", Job = "Programmer", Salary = 35000.00)
- LinqToSql DataContext#1 reads the record
- LinqToSql DataContext#2 reads the record and commits the following change (Salary = 50000.00)
- LinqToSql DataContext#1 attempts to commit the following change (Job = "Janitor")

With optimistic concurrency, DataContext#1 now gets a concurrency exception to resolve.  Without optimistic concurrency, we now have a janitor making 50k.

Comment: That makes sense; thanks for the explanation... But what about the case when you're only ever updating one field.  For instance, I have a popularity field on an Article table.  Every time someone views that article, I add points to the popularity column.  Ideally, I never want that column to not get updated due to conflicts.  So if 10 people view the article at once, I want the popularity field to be updated each time.  What is the best way to ensure this happens?  Is optimistic concurrency not the way to go here?

Comment: You either need concurrency, or you need a relative update SET ViewCount = ViewCount+1